# Get page coordinates of QgsComposerMap

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

How do I get the coordinates in page units (i.e. millimetres) for a `QgsComposerMap` item?

I can get the upper left coordinate using `pos`, but can't see any method that provides access to the width and height, or the lower right coordinate.

```
>>> map_item = composition.getComposerItemById('map')
>>> map_item.pos()
PyQt4.QtCore.QPointF(6.0, 6.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the width of the map item in millimetres:

```
map_item.rect().width()
```

And to get the height of the item:

```
map_item.rect().height()
```

Comment: We really want longer answers here. Please explain hat he is trying, where to try it and why trying it will help.